# Prove or disprove: If $Null(A-B)=\mathbb R^n$ then $ A=B $

Tags: linear-algebra

> $A$ and $B$ are matrices of order $m\times n$.
>
> Prove or disprove: If $Null(A-B)=\mathbb R^n$ then $ A=B $

Well I'm not sure I understand, does $Null(A-B)=\mathbb R^n$ means that the null span of $A$ minus the null span of $B$ equal to the span of $\mathbb R^n$ ?

**Edit:**

I got the solution: Let $(A-B)=M$ so using this: $$rank(M)+dim(null(M))=n$$  we can infer that $rank(M)=0 $ therefore $M=O\Rightarrow A=B$.

But I don't understand why the rank is 0 and why does that mean that the matrices' difference is $O$. Can anyone offer some insight ?

Comment: This refers to the null space of the $m \times n$ matrix $A - B$, not the difference of the null spaces.

Comment: Well then it's easy to disprove, take for example both matrices be the zero matrices.

Comment: If both matrices are zero, then they are equal.

Comment: Ah yes, so lets take $$ A=\begin{matrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 &0  \\ \end{matrix} $$ $$ B=\begin{matrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 &-1  \\ \end{matrix} $$

Comment: But isn't a counter example enough to disprove (and it's dimension doesn't matter) ?

Comment: The null space of that isn't $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Doesn't it equal to the span of $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: @GinKin The null space of $A - B$ is, in fact, $\{0\}$; so it's not a counterexample.

Comment: @T.Bongers why is it zero ? it should be $sp\{1,1\}$.

Comment: @GinKin $A - B$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, which has zero null space.

Comment: In other words, if Null(M)=$\mathbb{R}^n,$ prove or disprove $M=0.$

Comment: @MaxG. why? can you explain?

Comment: @Ginkin this has nothing to do with A or B, they are just trying to add in extra things to befuddle the problem solver. In the second part of the problem, instead of saying A=B one could say A-B=0 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try by contrapositive: if $A\neq B$, then there must be  some vector$~v$ such that $Av\neq Bv$. Then $(A-B)v\neq\ldots$

(continued) $\ldots\neq0$, since $(A-B)v=Av-Bv$ by definition. So $\def\Null{\operatorname{Null}}v\notin\Null(A-B)$ which proves $\Null(A-B)\neq\Bbb R^n$. We have shown $A\neq B\implies\Null(A-B)\neq\Bbb R^n$, which (as contrapositive) is equivalent to $\Null(A-B)=\Bbb R^n\implies A=B$.

Comment: I got the solution: $(A-B)=M$ so using this: $$rank(M)+dim(null(M)=n$$  we can infer that $rank(M)=0 $ therefore $M=O\Rightarrow A=B$. Although I don't understand why the rank is 0 and why does that mean that the matrices' difference is $O$. Your approach is obviously different, can you please finish it ?

Comment: @GinKin: I've lifted the suspense. But really, I think you could have found this yourself. Nothing is used except the definition of $A-B$, not even the fact that $A$ and $B$ are linear (even for arbitrary functions $f,g$, if $(f-g)(v)=0$ for all $v$, then $f=g$). Certainly using rank-nullity is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $Null(A-B) = \mathbb{R}^n$ then for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $(A - B)v = 0$. Try to use $v$ to your advantage here.

Comment: I don't see how to use it. You probably mean that I need to multiply $v$ by each column vector of $(A-B)$ so every column is equal zero but then what ?

Comment: Take $v = (1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. What does $(A-B)v=0$ tell you about the first column of $A-B$?

Comment: That only the first element in the column, say $e_1$  equal zero.